# How to use a javascript variable in url.action with ASP.NET MVC WebForms view engine

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, variables, url.action

I want to redirect the user to a url in a javascript function.

```
editClick: function () {
            var myid = 1;
            location.href = '<%= Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = myid})%>';

        };
```

But 'myId' does not exist in the current context. How do I use a js variable in Url.Action?

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  You cannot mix server- and client- side code.

Comment: I guess I shouldn't be using url.action and use an explicit url path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach that I've taken in the past is to generate the link in the view like so:

```
<div class='clickmaster'>
  <div class='clicker' id='@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = Model.Id })'>
    Show Something Here
  </div>
  <div class='clicker' id='@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = Model.Id })'>
     Show Something Here
  </div>
</div>
```

Then in the javascript I defined a function like this:

```
$(function() {
   $('.clickmaster').on('click', '.clicker' , function() { location.href = this.id; })
});
```

Comment: I really like that approach. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.  The best way to show appreciate on SO is to accept answers and vote up when you are able.

Comment: @duyn9uyen: The better way to do this is a `data-*` attribute.  (especially since IDs must be unique)